# How to sand wood without flattening it

Tags: wood, woodworking, sanding

I'd like to sand some wood planks on a rustic table to remove paint stains, but keep the rough wood structure (1-2 mm height difference). How can I do that?

Comment: sandblast, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sandpaper and your finger, or the edge/corner of a sanding block.

Though if you're just trying to remove paint I might first try using acetone or other solvent.

Answer (score 1):

Use a chemical stripper to remove the paint and a very fine grit sandpaper. You can get it clean this way without sanding away any wood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wire brush.  You would want one that is pretty stiff.

Whatever approach you decide - test on the bottom of the table first.